# What debugging should i add to fix my issue with spotipy not returning responses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, flask, spotipy

My below code was previously working and did all i needed it to, however has started stopping on the line:

```
tracks_data = self.sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_id)
```

Here is my full service script below, if you also have more suggestions on improving this in general for efficiency and cost reductions thats a bonus, however main focus is for this to work for now.

The function weekly_cache, will not complete anymore due to the line mentioned above stopping and halting the process, it doesnt crash, or provide errors, it gets to that line and stays there indefinitley.

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from google.cloud import storage 
import firebase_admin
import os
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
import json
import re


class SpotifyService:
    def __init__(self): # Initialize Variables and Stuff
        self.client_id = os.environ.get('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID')
        self.client_secret = os.environ.get('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET')

    self.client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=self.client_id, client_secret=self.client_secret)
    self.sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=self.client_credentials_manager)
    
    # Create a cache for playlist tracks and cover images
    self.playlist_cache = {}
    
    # Initialize Firebase Admin SDK with your Firebase credentials
    self.firebase_cred = credentials.Certificate('./API/new-waave-35fec48b08df.json')  # Replace with your Firebase credentials file path
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(self.firebase_cred)
    self.db = firestore.client()

    self.storage_client = storage.Client()
    self.bucket_name = 'waaveapibucket'  # Replace with your bucket name

    playlist_ref = self.db.collection('config').document('admin')
    playlist_doc = playlist_ref.get()
    data = playlist_doc.to_dict()
    playlist_ids = data.get('playlistIds', [])
    self.playlist_urls_or_ids = playlist_ids

def upload_to_bucket(self, blob_name, file_path): # Upload to Google Cloud Storage (Simple CRUD thing)
    """Upload data to a bucket."""
    bucket = self.storage_client.bucket(self.bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(file_path)

def read_file_to_array(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    # Remove newline characters from each line
    lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]
    return lines

def update_playlist_ids(self):
    try:
        # Read playlist IDs from file
        with open('./API/playlist_ids.txt', 'r') as file:
            lines = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]
        
        # Get the document reference
        playlist_ref = self.db.collection('config').document('admin')

        # Update the document
        playlist_ref.update({"playlistIds": lines})

        print(lines[20] if len(lines) > 20 else "Less than 21 lines in file")
        return 'success!!'
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error updating playlist Ids: {e}')
        return f'Error updating playlist Ids: {e}'

def get_playlist_cover(self, playlist_url): # Get Playlist Cover from Spotify ID

    if 'http' in playlist_url:
        parsed_url = urlparse(playlist_url)
        playlist_id = parsed_url.path.split('/')[-1]
    else:
        playlist_id = playlist_url

    try:
        cover_image = self.sp.playlist_cover_image(playlist_id)[0]['url']
        return cover_image
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error retrieving cover image for playlist {playlist_url}: {e}')
        return None

def parse_playlist_id(self, playlist_url_or_id): # Convert URLS to IDs
        if 'http' in playlist_url_or_id:
            parsed_url = urlparse(playlist_url_or_id)
            return parsed_url.path.split('/')[-1]
        return playlist_url_or_id

def weekly_cache(self):  # Cache this week's playlist Data/Results
    playlist_data = []
    data_to_remove = []
    print('Starting weekly_cache function.')

    for i, id in enumerate(self.playlist_urls_or_ids, 1):
        print(f"Processing playlist {i}: {id}")
        # If it's a URL, extract the playlist ID
        playlist_id = self.parse_playlist_id(id)
        print(f'Playlist ID for {i}: {playlist_id}')

        try:
            if playlist_id != 'test':
                print(f'Retrieving tracks for playlist ID {playlist_id}')
                tracks_data = self.sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_id)

                tracks = [
                    f"{item['track']['name']} - {', '.join(artist['name'] for artist in item['track']['artists'])}" 
                    for item in tracks_data['items'] if item['track']
                ]
                print(f'Found {len(tracks)} tracks for playlist ID {playlist_id}')

                cover_image = self.sp.playlist_cover_image(playlist_id)[0]['url']
                print(f'Cover image URL for playlist ID {playlist_id}: {cover_image}')

                playlist_entry = {
                    'playlist_id': playlist_id,
                    'cover_image': cover_image,
                    'songs': tracks
                }
                playlist_data.append(playlist_entry)
                print(f'Successfully processed playlist {playlist_id}')
            else:
                print(f'Skipping test playlist ID {playlist_id}')

        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error retrieving information for playlist {playlist_id}: {e}')
            data_to_remove.append(id)
            print(f'Added playlist ID {playlist_id} to removal list due to error.')

    print(f'Removing {len(data_to_remove)} playlists from the original list.')
    self.playlist_urls_or_ids = [item for item in self.playlist_urls_or_ids if item not in data_to_remove]

    temp_file = 'playlist_data.json'
    with open(temp_file, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(playlist_data, f, indent=4)
    print(f'Playlist data written to {temp_file}')

    # Upload the file to Google Cloud Storage
    self.upload_to_bucket('playlist_data.json', temp_file)
    print('Uploaded playlist_data.json to Google Cloud Storage')

    # Optionally, remove the temporary file if you don't need it locally
    os.remove(temp_file)
    print(f'Removed local file {temp_file}')

    # Update the Firestore database
    self.db.collection('config').document('admin').update({"playlistIds": self.playlist_urls_or_ids})
    print('Updated Firestore database with new playlist IDs')
def extract_urls(input_string):
    # Regular expression for matching URLs
    url_regex = r'https?://[^\s]+'
    urls = re.findall(url_regex, input_string)
    return urls

def get_cache(self): # Get JSON Cache of playlist Data
    """Read data from bucket and parse as JSON."""
    bucket = self.storage_client.bucket(self.bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob('playlist_data.json')

    # Download the contents of the blob as a string and then parse it as JSON
    json_data = json.loads(blob.download_as_string(client=None))
    return json_data

def get_playlists_containing_track(self, track_name, artist_name): # get data about playlists that have track in it
    playlist_data = self.get_cache()
    results = []

    for playlist in playlist_data:
        for index, song in enumerate(playlist['songs'], start=1):
            if track_name.lower() in song.lower() and artist_name.lower() in song.lower():
                results.append({
                    'playlist_id': playlist['playlist_id'],
                    'cover_image': playlist['cover_image'],
                    'position': index
                })

    return results
```

Please ignore indentation issues as this is stack overflow's copy & paste issue.
Also i have as you can tell, had chat gpt add in debug lines for me already, but it still halts after the print ('Retrieving tracks for playlist ID')

Comment: fyi: You are using Client Credentials. With that, you can get only playlist info from playlists that are publicly displayed at someone's profile.